# JSON generated manually works, but created through json.dumps does not work even if output seems to be exactly same

Tags: python, json, azure, databricks

I am using the `Marketo` API through the Python Library [marketo-rest-python](https://github.com/jepcastelein/marketo-rest-python). I can create Leads and also Update them through the following basic code:

```
leads = [{"email":"joe@example.com","firstName":"Joe"},{"email":"jill@example.com","firstName":"Jill"}]
lead = mc.execute(method='create_update_leads', leads=leads, action='createOnly', lookupField='email', 
                asyncProcessing='false', partitionName='Default')
```

When i create programmatically this "leads" JSON object via

```
leads = []

lead = {}
lead['email'] = "joe@example.com"
lead['firstName'] = "Joe"
leads.append(lead)

lead = {}
lead['email'] = "jill@example.com"
lead['firstName'] = "Jill"
leads.append(lead)

json_leads = json.dumps(leads, separators=(',', ':'))

print(json_leads)
```

Then the output is exactly the same within Microsoft Azure Databricks, but the Marketo system returns me an `609`-> Invalid JSON.

My output looks like

```
[{"email":"joe@example.com","firstName":"Joe"},{"email":"jill@example.com","firstName":"Jill"}]
```

Its exactly the same like in the sample. When i use the sample JSON codeline it works, but my self generated JSOn does not work.

Anyone has an idea what this ould be? I am using Python within Microsoft Azure Databricks.

Comment: if you execute `json.dumps(leads, separators=(',', ':') == manually_generated_json_string` in Python does it return true?

Comment: Without `json.dumps` by only using my `leads` array it works. With json.dumps not. Whats happens or what is the difference? Of course, i am replaceing/using the correct variable/object within the method.

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a string -- JSON is a string representation. It looks from @madprogrammer's answer that the function you are calling does not want JSON, it just wants python objects. I'm guessing that when you were saying "JSON generated manually" you actually were just writing python code, NOT a string -- and if it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: Very helpful thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! And if @madprogrammer's answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it "accepted". Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need to call `json.dumps`, just do it like this

```
leads = []

lead = {}
lead['email'] = "joe@example.com"
lead['firstName'] = "Joe"
leads.append(lead)

lead = {}
lead['email'] = "jill@example.com"
lead['firstName'] = "Jill"
leads.append(lead)

lead = mc.execute(method='create_update_leads', leads=leads, action='createOnly', 
lookupField='email', asyncProcessing='false', partitionName='Default')
```

Comment: Hm, ok it works. But it would be very helpful for me if you could explain why this happens! I would like to understand it.

Comment: The `mc.execute` function expects a python object, not a JSON string as the input for `leads` parameter, and you do pass it in your question. It's just a coincidence that your Python list of dicts happens to look exactly like a JSON string, but since there are no quotes, `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]` will be interpreted as a Python list containing two dicts, while `'[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]'` is a JSON string. In your case, the `mc.execute` function will do JSON encoding inside, so you don't need to.